# Defining a function outside main

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

main()
{
     float i;
     float x,N,sum;
     printf("enter x and N respectively");
     scanf ("%f %f", &x, &N);

     sum = 0;
     for (i=1;i<=N;i++){
          sum = sum + ((pow(x,i))/(fact(i)));
     }
     printf ("%f", sum);
}

int fact(int n){
     int i,temp;
     temp = 1;
     for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
          temp = temp*i;
          return temp;
     }

}
```

this is to print the summation of the terms accordingly. I tried defining fact inside main but there was some control flow warning and I tried the same outside this time, yet wrong answer. Any help?

Comment: `I tried defining fact inside main`...a clear sign of the need to read a good C book first. No offense.

Comment: You should *declare* functions *before using them*.

Comment: There are other errors in this code as well, such as the `return` statement in the factorial calculation loop.

Comment: Add a prototype, put the return statement after the loop.

Comment: Also, your return is inside `for` loop, so, only the first one iteration will be performed, and `fact` will always return `1`

Comment: But in Kernighan Ritchie there is a program where a the function is declared after using.

Comment: I forgot also, `temp = temp * i` will never do an addition. If you move your `return` statement after loop, `fact` will always return just `temp*n` instead of `temp!`

Comment: @user34304 BTW the K&R book is totally outdated.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot (you are forbidden by the C99 or C11 standard) define a function (like `fact`) inside another one (like `main`).

However, some C compilers, in particular [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) accept *as an extension* to have [nested functions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html).

<sup>(I don't recommend using that extension, in particular if you are newbie in C)</sup>

Of course you'll better *declare*

```
int fact(int n);
```

*before* your `main` and leave its *definition* after.

Your code is wrong (in particular, better *define* `main` as `int main(int argc, char**argv)` then learn perhaps about [getopt](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html#Getopt) and use it). Compile it with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g homework.c -o binaryprog`...) then use a debugger (e.g. `gdb ./binaryprog`)

Comment: and `main()` definitely is obsolescent written like that

Comment: Yes. And GCC can warn you about that..

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `int fact(int n);` before `main()` function to tell the compiler that a function called fact exists or you can add the whole function definition before.

Comment: Note: the program should compile with warnings (not errors) because `int` is the default return type.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare `fact()` above of main. There are 2 ways to do it.

First way: Add `int fact(int n);` above of main()

Second way: Copy the whole function above main(). So it looks like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int fact(int n)
{
    int i,temp;
    temp = 1;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++){
        temp = temp*i;
        return temp;
    }
}

main()
{
    float i;
    float x,N,sum;
    printf("enter x and N respectively");
    scanf ("%f %f", &x, &N);

    sum = 0;
    for (i=1;i<=N;i++){
        sum = sum + ((pow(x,i))/(fact(i)));
    }
    printf ("%f", sum);
}
```

Comment: Your first sentence is wrong: it doesn't need to "find" it. The program should compile with warnings (not errors) because `int` is the default return type.

Comment: Well, i guess i meant the same. You are right. My compiler gives me following warnings: - implicit declaration of function "fact"
- calling a function without a prototype